# Update Panel causes page to scroll to bottom of page

Tags: asp.net, scroll

I have an update panel setup on an asp.net webpage. Once i click on the button inside the update panel the date inside the updatepanel updates which is what i want but the page then scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="udpGender" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate> 
         <asp:Button ID="btnTest" TabIndex="-100" runat="server" Text="Click" />
         <p><%= System.DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

At the top of the page I have

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableTheming="true" %>
```

I have seen some javascript options but i was under the understanding this should happen automatically by .NET. This issue appears not be page specific but more website specific as its happening on multiple webpages. Im not using a masterpage for this particular webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not entirely sure, but Im such that if you use the Focus() method on the code behind for the button it will 'fix' the problem.

Lets say you have a textbox nameed 'txtName'
At the end of the button_click method, write: "txtName.Focus();"

Also if I may ask, whats the use of TabIndex? Does it affect the layout? Try debug with the attribute removed and see if it helps.

Comment: I was able to use what you suggested as a work around which is good enough for me for now. thank you